# How to restrict access on a FILE from being used (write/read) by another process or function in C?

Tags: c, variables

I'm currently having a problem updating the data written on a file in C. I created a function called **preview_data()** in loop that previews all the files written on **INFOS.DAT** constantly. I also created a function called **update_data()** that modifies **INFOS.DAT** if there's a new data available. I'm using **fwrite()** and **fread()** to modify the file.

However, I noticed that the changes made by **update_data()** is not taking effect. I suspect that this is because **INFOS.DAT** is being accessed every second by **preview_data()**.

Now with my question, how to restrict a file from being opened if it is being accessed by another process? Are there any way to know it so that I can create a break condition on my program? Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure without any code and data provided, but, generally speaking, `fwrite()` is not writing immediately. Instead, for performance reasons, it is buffering your input and writing a whole batch at once. Have you considered that possibility?

Comment: Files are data storage.  You're trying to use a file as a messaging channel.  That won't ever work well.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you are using the same file descriptor for opening and closing the file. You can overcome the problem by putting a 'MUTEX' lock on the file descriptor while reading or writing on the file.

Hence, if you are reading the file there will be a lock which will not allow to write in the file simultaneously and vice versa.

> NOTE : Please note that you may have to compromise with the performance of the program.

Answer (score 0):

In order to restrict access to a file, we need to lock the file. Locking a file can be done using two ways:
1) `flock`
2) `fcntl`

Refer this link:https://gavv.github.io/articles/file-locks/